# How to set Quality/Rendition of a video programmatically?

Tags: brightcove

I am implementing [Brightcove player](https://www.brightcove.com/en/player) in my website and I am facing problem in order to figure out how to set the video **Quality/Rendition** programmatically.

Any help and suggestions are heartily appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For DASH/HLS you can either use https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-quality-levels or the representations API (quality levels is preferred).

That said, i'd like to point it out that Brightcove has just released a new feature called [Context Aware Encoding](https://support.brightcove.com/context-aware-encoding).

Context Aware Encoding is a technology that uses machine learning to optimize encoding settings on a per-content item and delivery context basis. In a nut shell, it choose the best quality/rendition based on the size of the viewport and the bandwidth support of your ISP or mobile.

It will also help reduce the storage and bandwidth costs associated with video delivery, but without compromising visual quality.

Hope that helps.